# What is difference between after_create :some_method and after_create do end

Tags: ruby-on-rails

what is the main difference between these two callbacks ?

```
after_create do
  # ...
end
```

and

```
after_create :some_method

def some_method
   # ....
end
```

Comment: No difference in behaviour. First one is yielding the block while the second option is calling a method. The latter is more common though.

Comment: @Bartosz i think the first is for model and the second is for controller no ?

Comment: No. Controllers have `after_filter` and `before_filter` callbacks which works in the same way.

Comment: @Bartosz is correct – they are different ways of accomplishing _precisely_ the same thing.

Comment: okey well thank you @Bartosz :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wrap things up:

There is no difference in behaviour. First one is yielding the block while the second option is calling a method. The latter is more common though.

Controllers have `after_filter` and `before_filter` callbacks, which is working in the same way